# JQueryMobile Listview Filter Icon

Tags: listview, filter, jquery-mobile, icons

How to change the listview filter icon with an custom icon? Can't find it in the documentation or on SO..

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true">
</ul>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to overwrite this css with your own css (and change the link to the icon to the correct link, best to download the Jquery Mobile icons I think).

`.ui-icon-searchfield {
    background-image: url(images/icon-search-black.png);
    background-size: 16px 16px;`

http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0rc1/jquery.mobile-1.0rc1.zip

Contains the icons so that you can put them into your own images directory

Comment: direction is right, but now its filling 'all' the searchfield-background with many custom icons... any idea? and stil and more important, the old icon is still there, this seems not to be the correct solution.

Comment: yours + .ui-icon, .ui-icon-searchfield:after {
    background: none;
    border-radius: 9px 9px 9px 9px;
} = solution! thanks!